# xpath - how to select a hyperlink in a <tr> based on a <td> having certain content?

Tags: html, dom, xpath

I want to select a certain hyperlink in a table row.  My links have two categories 'mf' and '6day'.  I want to be able to select a row that has one of the above (only 1 row for now is fine) and then move along to the 2nd anchor tag and then store the link (storeAttribute).

So I have a table like this:

```
  ______________________________________
th |  td   | role|  td |  td |  td | td |
 _________________________________________
tr |  6day | a   | txt | txt | txt | a9 |
tr |  6day | a   | txt | txt | txt | a9 |
tr |  mf   | a   | txt | txt | txt | a1 | <-- the a1 here (2nd anchor link)
tr |  6day | a   | txt | txt | txt | a9 |
tr |  6day | a   | txt | txt | txt | a9 |
```

I want the row that has the plain text "mf" in it.

Then I want the "next" 'a'(anchor) tag i.e. the **a1** link (it's actually an 'a' not 'a1' but I used a1 to distinguish it).

I can select the **row** I want with:

`storeAttribute` with `xpath=(//table/tbody/tr/td[contains(text(),'Monday - Friday')])`

but trying to then select the next a tag within that row is baffling me.

I've tried the above with a variety of `/..//a`, `..//a`, etc. but no luck with them

I can use this: `xpath=(//table/tbody/tr[3]/td[8]/a)` but that is dependent on the layout of the table so is too brittle for my needs.

The 'real' HTML table is at: http://jsfiddle.net/8LJMu/

Answer (score 1):

You want `(//table[@id='practitioners']/tbody/tr[td[contains(@class, 'calendar') and contains(.,'Monday - Friday')]]//td[@class='']/a[@target='_blank'])[1]` - literally, "the first item of the node-list composed of all anchor elements with a "_blank" target attribute contained in any cell with no CSS class contained in any rows in the 'practitioners' table that contain a 'calendar' cell containing "Monday - Friday".  If you're looking for all such cells, just remove the leading `(` and the trailing `)[1]`.

Comment: +1 Useful but I am not going for the role links (which are also on the tr row) - they are that first 'a' - and I want the next anchor, 'a1'

Comment: Updated to show how to find the login link cell as requested.